# I need to extract a request number from "response data"

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use Regular expression extractor to extract, but i don't know how to use it here. Since the "request number" is visible only in "Response Data" of "View result tree". where should i place the post processor. what would be my regular expression.

[image]

[image]
[image]

edit: I have added my regular expression and result screen

Answer (score 1):

Your response value is a *number*, without double quotes, so change your Regular expression to

```
 "response":(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON data using regular expressions is not the best idea, I believe you should be using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead.

It's available since [JMeter version 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) and you should be able to use it instead of the Regular Expression Extractor.

The relevant JsonPath query will be as simple as:

```
$.response
```

Full configuration just in case:

[image]

---

Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.0](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.0.zip) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.